# Should I write an algorithm that decrypts a string into a list of items or force the dowloading of an updated DB regularly for a React Native App?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, react-native, optimization, nosql

Without revealing too much about my program; I am creating an app that helps manage inventory of products in storage units. The problem is that the app needs to function without internet connection for short periods of time(roughly 5 minutes at a time). Currently I have a MongoDB setup that stores the contents of each storage unit and I run queries to the DB to get the requested info. Naturally, the function doesn't work when there is no signal/connection to the DB so I am stuck between two options:

1. Have the app automatically store(on the phone) an updated DB that is updated every 15 minutes(assuming there is a stable connection) that can be accessed and manipulated offline and updated once there is signal.
2. Or create a sophisticated algorithm that can convert a string(maybe 32 chars long) into the list of products and data that the user needs to access offline. I believe this is called hashing.

As far as my concerns; I don't want to have the app consume a large amount of space for the user. The demographic phone that will be using this app has a limited space capacity so keeping the app under 70Mb is a soft cap goal. In regards to computing time it obviously depends on the optimization of the code and I'm not sure really how sophisticated of an algorithm I would need to convert a string of say 32 characters into a list of <100 items with properties: name, unit quantity, and image directory(online mode only), total quantity, etc.

If anything is unclear please don't hesitate to ask away and if you suggest that a "decryption algorithm" is the best option then any guidance towards that path would be very much appreciated(example code, youtube videos, stack overflow posts)

Comment: I'm not really clear on how hashing some data gets around having no internet connection. They seem like two different domains to me (1 is caching, 2 is hashing).

Comment: As of now, the program requests information to a DB that stores a table of individual storage units and their contents. If I want to be able to receive the same information, without internet access, can I create a backup algorithm that hashes a 6 (alphanumeric) character code to determine the contents of each storage unit. More specifically each storage unit will have anywhere between 1 and 100 different products with varying quantities and each product has a name string variable, and id value(int).

Comment: Where does the client get this string from (if not the internet)?

Comment: Okay now I understand the source of confusion.
The main function of the program is to help identify the contents of a storage unit. After the user fills the new storage unit by scanning each item, the application generates a unique 6 char. code(via an algorithm) and adds the unit into a DB if internet is available. Regardless if there is internet available, the application should be able to receive a 6 char code, from the user, and return the contents of a storage unit. The code generated is used to label each storage unit.